# Edit server code without restarting?

Tags: express

After I have started an Express server, is there some code I can execute in that runtime environment that can change the server? Or at least add a new endpoint and disable an old one?

I'm interested in any kind of solution even if it's a bit hacky.

Here's what I want in the end:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

function foo() {
  app.make_new_endpoint('get','/new-endpoint','res.send("Hola!")');
});
```

Comment: @jtmarmon gave a good solution and i would also add https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2 it offers similar options.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/remy/nodemon

When you save changes to a file it'll automatically restart the api for you seamlessly. No hacks needed